# <i className='fa fa-Email-square'></i> is not showing icon

Tags: reactjs

is not showing icon properly. Instead if I use Facebook in the place of Email then it works but in the case of Email, it does not showing icon

Comment: ```<i class="fa fa-envelop-square"></i>``` not ```Email``` it's ```envelop```

Comment: Try this 
`<i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

it is not email it is envlop instead you can try `<i class="fa fa-envelop-square"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

Envelop wont work as its envelope so try using this

`<i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>`